# Form submit problem using JavaScript in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I have just done the code for submit the form using JavaScript.

It works in all browsers except in Internet Explorer 6.

I have pasted my HTML form and JavaScript code below.

Can you please find what's the problem with it?

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function dodelete(image_id)
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete this image?"))
        {
            document.getElementById('image_id').value=image_id;
            document.del_form.submit();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

HTML Code:

```
    <form name="del_form" id="del_form" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="do" id="do" value="delete" />
        <input type="hidden" name="image_id" id="image_id" />
    </form>
```

Function Call Code:::

```
<p class="video">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="dodelete('<?php echo $row['image_id']?>')">                                 
    <img src="<?php echo $cfg->admin_image_path; ?>/delete_icon1.gif" border="0" alt="Delete"/>
   </a>
</p>
```

Comment: You might want to consider posting this question on serverfault.com instead.

Comment: Severfault??? Why? This is a programming related question.

Comment: Please add the call to `dodelete`.

Comment: i have added code for calling dodelete....

Comment: its replace the value of image id using document.getElementById('image_id').value=image_id;
But after that it is not submitting the form.

Comment: i have alerted the following code in js function.
document.getElementById('image_id')
its displaying only object not a object object in ie 6.
Can be this is the problem with my script.

Comment: The code looks oddly familiar... where did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

What is returned by:

`document.getElementById('image_id')`

It returns one `INPUT` element of collection of elements?

Try to replace:

`document.getElementById('image_id').value=image_id;`

with:

`document.del_form.image_id.value=image_id;`

Answer (score 0):

OnSubmit call for javascript would help.

```
<form name="del_form" id="del_form" onsubmit="dodelete(value);" >
    <input type="hidden" name="do" id="do" value="delete" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_id" id="image_id" />
</form>
```

Comment: hi,
here onclick of delete image, after confirmation it will write the image is to the hidden field and submit that form.
So here form is used to just hold the image_id.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I'd like to try, I'm not sure why or when this doesn't work it seems random, first try to set a timeout for the submit :

```
document.doSubmit = function() {
    document.del_form.submit();
}
setTimeout("document.doSubmit();", 100);
```

Sometimes, just `return` something after the click works :

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_id" id="image_id" onclick="submitFormFunction(); return false;” />
```

Comment: hi thanks for your ans, but i m not getting what r u trying to explain? :-)

Comment: but in my functionality there is no onclick event of image_id.
my js function will execute on click of the delete image.
and it will fill the image id to the my del_form form.
and after filling form it will submit the form using javascript..

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you replace:

```
    document.del_form.submit();
```

with:

```
document.getElementById('del_form').submit()
```

Comment: When are you invoking `dodelete`? Do you get any errors? If so what are they?

Comment: dodelete will invoke by clicking on the image, no i m not getting any erros.

Comment: Does it change the value? Is your markup 100% valid? No duplicate ids? Can you post an example?

Comment: K.. try alerting document.getElementById('foo') of the form, does it say object Object in IE6? And is your markup 100% valid?

Comment: i have alerted the following code in js function.
document.getElementById('image_id')
its displaying only object not a object object in ie 6.
Can be this is the problem with my script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `method='POST'` to the beginning of `form` element definition.

I mean -- `method` attribute should be the first attribute of `form` element.

If I remember well, this fixed some problems with submitting forms on IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code a little bit.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    function dodelete(image_id) 
    { 

        if (confirm("Are you sure want to delete this image?")) 
        { 

            document.getElementById('image_id').value=image_id; 
            document.del_form.submit(); 
        } 
 return false;
    } 
</script>
```

and the HTML with some test `Image ID` and it works in IE6

```
<form name="del_form" id="del_form" method="post" onSubmit="return(dodelete('2'));"> 
        <input name="do" id="do" value="delete" /> 
        <input name="image_id" id="image_id"  /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try again :).

What happen after replacing:

`onclick="dodelete('<?php echo $row['image_id']?>')">`

with:

`onclick="dodelete('<?php echo $row['image_id']?>'); return false;">`

What exactly doesn't work with your code? Throw JS error, there is no server request, values in request are empty?

And (maybe the most important question) -- where is `action` attribute for your `del_form` form?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
```

with

```
<a href="#"
```

IE have problem with that for the dom that fires the JS submit.